# a img tags dont know how to

Tags: css, image, html

Size of the link is short, after this code link is only created on the 32x18px and image size is 32x32px. i dont understand why :/ you can see the site yourself.

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Masala-Grill/
1392418307667401?ref=hl">
<img alt="Masal Grill Facebook" title="Masal Grill Facebook" src="http://masala-
grill.biz/assets/images/facebook.png" border="0" width="32"></a>
```

CSS is this:

```
color: #a59f9f;
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 16px;
```

Comment: Could you explain a little more? It's a little unclear what you are asking.

Comment: There is no text in your link to affect with that CSS.

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking, but you have width="32" but no height="32" - try adding a "height" attribute if the height is only 18px and you want it to be 32?

Comment: you can see this site http://masala-grill.biz/ the top left facebook link , image size is 32x32 and the link is only on 32x18 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very confusing.  You want the `<a>` tag to be 32x32 px?

If the css you included in the question is css for the `<a>` tag, simply add this css to make the tag 32x32 pixels:

```
display:block;
width:32px;
height:32px;
```

Comment: yeah thanks !! i really want this